# How is it that Meteor.methods is made with "native code"?

Tags: meteor

When doing `console.log(Meteor.methods)` in the browser, the result is

```
function () { [native code] }
```

I thought `[native code]` was for functions that are implemented in the browser? Meteor.methods is not built into Chrome, for example. How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Meteor.methods` is a rebind of another JS function: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/client_convenience.js#L52. There is nothing special about it other than it is a result of `Function.bind`. Try it in your console:

```
x = function () {}
y = x.bind(null, 1)
```

If you print `y`, it will be `[native code]` because Chrome doesn't know how to print bound functions best.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting why they'd choose to do that.